# how to get single out put from image tag with simplexml_import_dom?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, simplexml

I have extracted images from a webpage with the code bellow, but i only want to get the second "image" and "alt" in the data.

```
"image: /images/2.png
Alt : image 2"
```

any help would be much appreciated.

```
@$dom->loadHTML($page);
    
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
    
    $images = $xml->xpath('//img');
    
    foreach ($images as $img) {
        
        if (isset($img["src"]) && isset($img["alt"])) 
            echo "image: " . $img['src'] . "<br />";
            echo "Alt : " . $img['alt'] . "<br />";
    
    }
```

return:

```
image: /images/1.png
Alt : image 1

image: /images/2.png
Alt : image 2

image: /images/3.png
Alt : image 3
```

Answer (score 0):

[xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) returns an array, so `$images` is an array
You could access the second element like `$images[1]`.

`$images[1]` is then of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and you can access the attributes like:

```
$src = $images[1]->attributes()->src;
$alt = $images[1]->attributes()->alt;
if ($src && $alt) {
    echo "image: " . $src . "<br />";
    echo "Alt : " . $alt . "<br />";
}
```

Or you could update the xpath expression to:

```
$images = $xml->xpath('//img[2]');

if (isset($images[0])) {
    // etc ..
}
```